# DateTime Format change

Tags: c#

I am having date time variable in dd-MMM-yyyy format and I have to convert it to  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:SS.Very new to C#. But had done some datetime to string conversion like this

```
public string FormatDate(string param1)
{
 return DateTime.Parse(param1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

But dont know how to convert just the format and not the datatype.

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: This looks a bit like you're doing this for insert into an sql database. If that's the case, you're making a huge mistake, and likely writing very insecure code.

Comment: I am using this in BizTalk where I get the data from Oracle DB source which is in DateTime but with dd-MMM-yyyy but have to insert it into the SQLDatabase datetime which has to be  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:SS.

Comment: @xyz That statement doesn't make sense. A `DateTime` represents a date & a time _without_ any formatting. Dates only have formatting when you translate them to strings. You shouldn't even try converting the `DateTime` to a string between two databases.

Comment: when I was trying to insert the data , i was getting this error  "  The input data for the field/parameter "e_date" is invalid according to the expected SqlDbType DateTime. ---> System.FormatException: The string '04-DEC-65' is not a valid AllXsd value."

Comment: I am not sure how to approach this, thought if I can change the formats and check if that works.Dont know why lots of downgrade.

Comment: @xyz - no worries look at the answers below between the two they have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Convert a String to a DateTime (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx)

```
// Date strings are interpreted according to the current culture. 
// If the culture is en-US, this is interpreted as "January 8, 2008",
// but if the user's computer is fr-FR, this is interpreted as "August 1, 2008" 
string date = "01/08/2008";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);            
Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Day: {2}", dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);

// Specify exactly how to interpret the string.
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", true);

// Alternate choice: If the string has been input by an end user, you might  
// want to format it according to the current culture: 
// IFormatProvider culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(date, culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Day {2}", dt2.Year, dt2.Month, dt2.Day);

/* Output (assuming first culture is en-US and second is fr-FR):
    Year: 2008, Month: 1, Day: 8
    Year: 2008, Month: 8, Day 1
 */
```

Comment: Please add a note showing how to pass this to an insert or other sql statement using a datetime data type.

Answer (score 1):

The first mistake here is that you have a string variable at all. A comment on the question indicates this data came from an Oracle DB. C# is perfectly capable of reading a DateTime value directly from an Oracle result set, without needing to use a string. Converting it to a string makes your system do additional work (it's bad for performance) and introduces potential for conversion error (it's bad for correctness/can introduce bugs). I'd show the right way to read the data, but I'd need to see your existing code for this to create a good example.

Secondly, a basic premise of the question is incorrect. C# DateTime variables *never* use `dd-MMM-yyyy` format (although a string variable might). Instead, DateTime variables use a binary format that is not human readable. You only see it in a recognizable format as a convenience provided by your debugger. Additionally, the further premise of the question that you need to get to the `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:SS` format is incorrect, because Sql Server also does not use any human-readable format. The string format is (again) just a convenience provided by your query tool.

**If you're working with a database and are worried about a string format for a date value, you're doing it horribly *wrong*.**

The only time you might ever need a specific format for a date with a database is if you wanted to include that value in an sql query string. This implies the use of a flawed technique that will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Never **ever** write code like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO [Table] VALUES ('" + MyVariable + "')";
```

String concatenation + sql like that is *vulnerable to sql injection attacks.* Instead, you need code that looks like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO [Table] VAlUES ( @MyParameter )";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyParameter", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = MyDateTimeVariable;
```

Doing it this way avoids a **massive** security issue. It has performance benefits in terms of re-using query plans. In other words, you should do this for **all** variables that you want to include with Sql code... *every time*. As a nice side-effect, this also neatly avoids the problem of how to format your DateTime variable. ADO.Net will instead deliver the variable to the database already in Sql Server binary format... there'll be nothing to convert. .

In summary: read a .Net DateTime directly from Oracle. Write a .Net DateTime directly to Sql Server. Don't worry about formatting, and fix a major security issue.

Comment: This combined with @TarasKovalenko 's answer which shows you how to get a DataTime type is how you solve your problem